# Repeat elements of list between each other until we reach a certain length

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that starts with numbers and has nan's near the end

`[1,2,3, nan, nan, nan, nan]`

I want to spread out the available numbers over the entire length of my list until all nan's are overwritten.

There are nan's in our list, we start with the first number: `[1, 1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan]` is there still nan left in the list? yes: `[1,1,2,2,3, nan, nan]` ... `[1,1,2,2,3,3,nan]` ... if all nan's are overwritten the list will look like

`[1,1,1,2,2,3,3]`

what is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

edit:

the nan is a numpy.nan, this can be replaced by None

Comment: What is the replacement rule? How do you decide which number replaces NaN? The frequency?

Comment: what's your code until now? any efford yet?

Comment: the numbers available in the list should be spread out over the length of the list. we start with [1, 1, 2, 3, nan, nan,nan] is there still nan left in the list? if yes [1,1,2,2,3, nan, nan] ... [1,1,2,2,3,3,nan] ... [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]. we repeat until all nan's are replaced.

Comment: output of `[1, 1, 1,None, 2, 3, 3]`?

Comment: @VincentClaes make the changes in your question and add the replacement rules there :).

Comment: Pythonic is a fuzzy and often misused term.  Write a function that does the correct replacement for one `nan`, and apply it repeatedly until done.

Comment: Is that `nan` the `numpy.nan` or something else?  Why the `numpy` tag?

Comment: This is nowhere near well enough defined. What should happen, for example, if there are `nan`s *not* at the end of the list? Is it good enough to: find the non-nans; use math to figure out how many times to repeat the elements; make a new list with the elements repeated the appropriate number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, a `numpy` solution :

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]) # an example
n=len(a)
p=n-np.isnan(a).sum() # count of valids assuming nan's at the end.
repeats=n//p
m=n-repeats*p # number of overfilled.
q=m*(repeats+1) #border
a[q:]=a[m:p].repeat(repeats) #the end
a[:q]=a[:m].repeat(repeats+1) #the beginning
```

result :

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.])
```

Comment: Turning the list into an array isn't cheap, and it changes integers into floats (`nan` is a float).  For large lists this numpy solution may be faster, but probably not for small ones.

Comment: Yes. The initial post has a numpy tag, so I suppose that initial data can be a numpy array ?

Comment: @B.M. yes idd, this can be a numpy array

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution that counts how many times each list element must be repeated

```
import itertools as it
l = [1, 2, 3, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']

off = l.index('nan') # offset of the first 'nan' element
subl = l[:off] # to avoid slicing more than once

rem = len(l) % off # remainder
rep = len(l) // off # min repetitions

rep_el = (rep+1 if p < rem else rep for p,el in enumerate(subl))
newl = it.chain(*(it.repeat(el,r) for el,r in zip(subl, rep_el)))

print(list(newl))
```

which produces

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

`rem` is the remainder of the division of the total number of elements in the list and the number of elements that aren't 'NaN'

`rep` is the minimum number of repetitions all elements have

`rep_el` is a generator that contains the repetitions each list element must have. If the position of the element is less than the remainder it means its repetition should be increased by one.

`newl` is the newly formed list. It is built by concatenating the repetitions generated by repeating each element for the correct number of times as calculated above.

Comment: @VigneshKalai you are free to experiment further. But why avoid itertools?

Comment: I wanted to go it without importing and wanted it to be simple :).

Answer (score 3):

### Iterative solution

Here's an iterative solution, trying to match the logic in the question:

```
x = [1,2,3,None,None,None,None,None]  # replace nan with None

def onestep(cur,y,base):
    # one step of the iteration
    if cur is not None:
        y.append(cur)
        base.append(cur)
    else:
        y.append(base[0])  # append is simplest, for now
        base = base[1:]+[base[0]]  # rotate
    return base

y=[]
base=[]
for cur in x:
    base = onestep(cur,y,base)
    # print(base,y)
print(y)
```

which produces:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

I tried to keep track of a `base` index, the element of the base that I was going insert next. But it proved to be simpler to just rotate the `base`, and always use the 1st element.

I started with a `j` index that I stepped through `x`, but then realized I didn't need it to reference `x[j]`.  I could just use `for cur in x:`.

### Iterative solution - 2nd version

Lets refine it to collect the values in the desired order.  To do this I need to keep track on an insertion point. But that proved to be difficult.  So I switched to the idea I used before (see below) - collect sublists.

```
def onestep1(cur,y,i):
    # initial and extend sublists
    if cur is not None:
        y.append([cur])
    else:
        if i>len(y)-1:
            i = 0
        y[i].append(y[i][0])
        i += 1
    return i

y=[]
i = 0
for cur in x:
    i = onestep1(cur,y,i)
print(y, i)
```

producing

```
([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]], 2)
```

which can be flattened with `chain`:

```
print(list(itertools.chain(*y)))
```

producing:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

In this case I still need to keep track of a `i` index, indicating which sublist is up for incrementing.

An alternative to `chain` is a double comprehension:

```
[i for j in y for i in j]
```

### Global repetition

An alternative is to step back from the iteration details, and look at the big picture.

Start with a list; lets replace `nan` (a numpy float) with `None`, a pure Python value.  But it could be almost any distinct 'fill' value:

```
In [188]: x=[1,2,3,None,None,None,None,None]
```

where does it start?

```
In [190]: idx = x.index(None)
In [191]: idx
Out[191]: 3
```

What are the base values that we want to repeat?

```
In [192]: base = x[:idx]
In [193]: base
Out[193]: [1, 2, 3]
```

We want, in effect, to repeat each value of `base` as many times as needed to fill a list the length of `x`.  Viewed this way it isn't really a replacement problem.  It's, how to expand one list of `n` items into a list of `m` items.

In this example we want to repeat the 3 values `cnt` times:

```
In [194]: cnt=[3,3,2]
```

`numpy` has a nice function for applying `cnt`, `np.repeat`:

```
In [195]: np.repeat(base, cnt)
Out[195]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Sticking with lists we can do:

```
In [196]: [[i]*j for i,j in zip(base,cnt)]
Out[196]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

But this a nested list.   A nice, idiomatic way of flattening a nested list is with `itertools.chain`.  It is quite 'pythonic' to make use of tools that the standard library provides.  It's good practice to become familiar with `itertools`:

```
In [197]: list(itertools.chain(*[[i]*j for i,j in zip(base, cnt)]))
Out[197]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Another way to apply `cnt` is with a double comprehension (replacing both the list * and `chain`.

```
[i for i,c in zip(base, cnt) for _ in range(c)]
```

I could calculate the `cnt` list with the same sort of logic as in `onestep` (or `onestep1`), except accumulate a count value rather than sublist.

Or as the other answers show, we can reason from the length of `base` and the total length, using the integer division and modulus to figure out how many counts should be `n`, and how many `n-1`.

Mathematically the problem is:

```
Integers, m, n, such that:
8 = (3-m)*n + m*(n-1)
8 = 3*n -m*n + m*n - m = 3*n - m
n = (8//3) + 1 (= 3); m = 3*n - 8 (= 1)
cnt = [n]*(m-1) + [n-1]*(m) (=[3]*2 + [2]*1 = [3,3,2])
```

`Pynchia's` expression does the same thing:

```
rep_el = (rep+1 if p < rem else rep for p,el in enumerate(subl))
```

I would not consider any of these more 'pythonic' than the others.  They are different strategies, but can all be written in good Python style.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (if I understand your question right):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, None, None, None, None]
result = [x for x in my_list if x is not None]
result.extend([result[i%len(result)] for i in xrange(len(my_list)-len(result))])
result.sort()
```

If you have to save original order just replace last string to:

```
result.sort(key=lambda x: my_list.index(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = '123'
i = 0
j = 0
while 'nan' in list_a:
  if i = len(r):
    i = 0
  if(list_a[j] == 'nan'):
    list_a[j] = r[i]
    i += 1
  j += 1
```

## I think this should solve it.

Comment: Plus, of course yes then you will have to just call the list_a.sort()

Comment: I think it's not enough pythonic)

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by pythonic? I'm new so quite don't understand what you mean..

Comment: I thought the aim of code was to simplify things. But anyway :-)

Comment: a) BE HUMBLE: never assume yours is the best solution. b) Eugene means python seldom needs to use indexing since it provides many ways and tools to iterate. Furthermore, you solution seems to be incomplete: start with the proper input (i.e. a list in the form `[1, 2, 3, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']`) and produce the desire output. Please.

Comment: The OP didn't give us anything to simplify.  He just asked for this vague 'pythonic' attribute.  If it runs  and conforms to PEP8 (or what ever), it's Pythonic, right?  He didn't ask for 'numpy-onic' (though there's a numpy tag).